# PHP LOAD DATA INFILE VS Fopen

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I tried for the second attempt to use LOAD DATA INFILE to upload records from CSV into MySQL database but I always encounter errors in all of my attempts, different errors every time which is why I'd rather use the primitive way of looping through the records.

My last script:

```
<?php

//Connect to Database
$maindir = realpath(__DIR__);
include($maindir . '/connectme.php');

$queme = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $_FILES['fromfileupload']['tmp_name'] . "'
INTO TABLE thecardb
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY ',,,\\r\\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(carid, carname, carbrand, carprice, carcolor)" ; 

if (mysqli_query($concon, $queme))
{
   echo "Success";
}
?>
```

My most recent error is

`Access denied for user '########_######'@'##.#.#.##' (using password: YES)`

I replaced parts of the error as # for confidentiality reasons.

This is and has always been irritating for me, I believe part of the issue is due to some permission settings in php.ini or from other PHP configurations that I can't seem to access or find (I'm using webhosting and not running this site on my own server). Will I be fine using fopen() to upload records from a CSV instead of using LOAD DATA INFILE? I think it's my most simple solution right now that could work (using mysqli_multi_query). I am only dealing with about 5000-10000 records.

Answer (score 0):

Erm... I think the error message pretty much has told you what is the problem.

Access denied.

A few things you should check...

1. User account and passwords. Are they correct?
2. Does that account have access to that database?
3. Does that account have access to the table you are loading data into?
4. Does that account have rights to run the load data command?

That should cover about all you need to check for now...

Comment: Thank you for that but please read my post, I am already aware of the possible security issues. Yes to #1-#3 and the problem is #4, again I am using a web hosting plan for my website and accessing certain configurations like php.ini is a problem for me.

My question is, would it be alright to use fopen or other looping techniques to add 5000 records to the database as I am planning to just go that way

Comment: Yes, it would be fine. Just create a [prepared statement](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and then loop over the file via [fgetcsv](http://docs.php.net/fgetcsv), assign the values to the bound parameters ([list()](http://docs.php.net/list) might be helpful here) and execute the statement. 5k records ...that's nothing ;-)